# best practices for dynamic content

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a pretty extensive Classic ASP background (using server-side javascript), and my company is finally (FINALLY) making the push towards recoding everything in ASP.Net (using C#). I have a good grasp on good programming practices in Classic ASP and I usually try to make sure I code things the "right" way. I've been reading ASP.Net tutorials and feel like I have a pretty understanding of the basics. I have good discipline about separating client side javascript into external js files, keeping styling outside of the markup in external css files, etc. So, when reading these novice tutorials I understand the concept of the code-behind pages. It makes sense to me to separate the c# code from what will ultimately become the markup for the page. Making < asp:button > objects and the code-behind rules to alter them makes perfect sense.

However, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to do something simple like I would have done in Classic ASP like this:

```
<%
   if (condition) {
      %>
         <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="dosomething()" />
      <%
   }
   else {
      %>
         <span>You don't have permission to see the button</span>
      <%
   }
%>
```

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how I'm supposed to fit the conditional stuff you see above into the code-behind page. If I was showing a button under both circumstances, I'd make an `<asp:button>` object and style it in the code-behind page accordingly - but in the example above I'm only showing the button if the condition is true, and a span block if false.

I know that you don't HAVE to put ALL the c# code in the code-behind page. I can use the `<% %>` tags the same way I would do in Classic ASP. But, if I do that then it seems to me that it lessens the relevance of the code-behind page. For example, I know you can use an external css stylesheet to stylize your page and at the same time use inline styles on individual tags as well. I believe this to be poor practice, however. It makes it difficult to later have to adjust the styles on that element if you don't know whether to look in the markup or in the css file to find the relevant styles affecting that element.

It seems to me that the same would hold true for your markup and code-behind pages. Is it just a necessary evil to have to mix the 2, or is there a better way to do what I'm demonstrating above?

Comment: Your question needs some editing. You should make the first paragraph a description of the problem you're facing, not irrelevant background information. Also consider making it clear what the question you're asking is.

Comment: Coming from ASP, it may be easier to transition to ASP.NET MVC, instead of web forms.  MVC is more syntactically similar to ASP...  But I know you probably don't have a lot of control over that :-)

Comment: As you write that you're finally moving to asp.net from asp classic.. I'd suggest jumping to asp.net mvc ( http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4 ), It has much more power and much easier to work with, you have a more asp like alternative (without the mvc part) with the web api: ( http://www.asp.net/web-api ), Don't take a step forward to an old technology ;)

Comment: @AdamFridental To be entirely fair to Web Forms, there are use cases where it's more convenient. (Coding multiple-step stateful workflows when you don't need bookmarkability and don't particularly feel like doing this in JS, or quick-and-dirty AJAX with an UpdatePanel.) That said it certainly isn't progressing anywhere near the pace of MVC.

Comment: @millimoose I won't argue with what you say, but I geuss that most of those dirty things can be made elegantly with a SPA technology. But if you're ok with getting your hands dirty, go for it ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could have in your markup:

```
<asp:Button .. Visible="False" />
<asp:Label .. Text="You do not have permissions" Visible="False" />
```

Note the Visible property.  ASP.NET web forms is build on the idea of an object model, so the button and label are objects you can work with.  In the code behind, you can have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    .
    .

    if (Xcondition = true) {
       Button1.visible=  true;
       Label2.Visible = false;
    }
    else {
       Button1.visible=  false;
       Label2.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Is the traditional way to accomplish this.  You just have to figure out where in the lifecycle you need to do this, as load may not be the best (Init or PreRender event, for instance).  If you only need to do this at startup once, do `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { .. }` to ensure it only runs once.

Comment: Will the Visible property prevent the element from being served to the client altogether, or will it be served with a display:none style?

If the button (or span, or div, etc) contained admin-only sensitive information then it would be imperative that information not be served to the client, even in non-visible form.

Comment: With this approach he's mixing his client UI code in with his code behinds. This is one of the many things wrong with ASP.NET WebForms. As others have already noted, he should consider going forward with MVC 4.

Comment: @MikeP: Nonetheless the question specifies web forms pretty exactly, and this is an answer to the question as stated.

Comment: Also, unless you're eschewing setting attributes in the `.aspx` code, it's rather pointless to do this in `Page_Init`. Using `PreRender` also clobbers any changes made to that property as event handlers are dispatched. There are cases when you want either of these, but they're not nearly as common.

Comment: @kaht: for controls in asp.net, if visible is false, the control is not rendered to the final page so it will not be possible for a non-admin user to see the button even in the source

Comment: Yes control would not be rendered to the client, so there would be no client footprint.  In the scheme of things, it really doesn't matter Init/Load/PreRender, unless something else is working with the control.  I love MVC, but if your company says web forms, you got to go with it...

Answer (score 1):

I made a small example that you can basically just copy/paste and mess around with a little.

This is the aspx code:

```
 < body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCondition"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Check condition" ID="btnCheckCondition" OnClick="btnCheckCondition_Click" />

        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click me" ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Visible="false"/>
        <asp:Label runat="server"  ID="lblMsg"></asp:Label>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

this is the code behind: (if you double click on the btnCheckCondition, the click_event method will be automatically generated in your codebehind.

```
  protected void btnCheckCondition_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtCondition.Text == "Show the button")
            {
                btnSubmit.Visible = true;
                lblMsg.Text = "You are allowed to see the button.";

            }
            else
            {
                lblMsg.Text = "You are NOT allowed to see the button.";

            }
        }
```

This will basically check the input in the textbox `txtCondition`. If it is equal to "Show the button", the second button will become visible. If the text is something else, the button will not appear and a label will say that you are not allowed to see the button.

Comment: This is the standard way to do it in ASP.NET w/o extraneous requirements.

Answer (score 0):

have a label and a button in the page. check the condition from code behind and based on the condition, hide or show the control. you can use visibility attribute of the controls to hide or show them. Also use asp.net controls so that you can access them from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a good reason not to, use the [`Visible` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible.aspx). (In ASP.NET Web Forms, you're asking for trouble if you change the structure of the component tree dynamically other than using repeater controls.) What I do is:

#### Page.aspx

```
<button type='button' Visible='<%# condition %>' runat='server'>
    Click Me!
</button>
<span Visible='<%# !condition %>' runat='server'>
    No button for you!
</span>
```

#### Page.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load() {
    if (!IsPostBack) DataBind(); // evaluates <%# ... %> expressions
}
```

(My preference is to make controls to "pull" data from code-behind instead of pushing it there, and use anonymous and plain HTML controls over their heavier equivalents when possible.) Any way of setting `Visible` before the page renders will work though.

Answer (score 0):

First to help you with the easy way, to been able the `condition` to been recognized you need to define it and make it public on code behind. For example:

```
<%if (condition) {%>
    <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="dosomething()" />
<%}else { %>
    <span>You don't have permission to see the button</span>
<% } %>
```

and on code behind

```
public partial class OnePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public bool condition = false;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // here change the condition
    }
}
```

### Second case with function call

```
<%if (fCheckAuth()) {%>
    <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="dosomething()" />
<%}else { %>
    <span>You don't have permission to see the button</span>
<% } %>
```

and on code behind

```
public partial class OnePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public bool fCheckAuth()
    {
        // return your evaluate
        return false;
    }    
}
```

### More asp.net form style

Now, working with the new asp.net (compared with the classic asp) you can also do that (and similar to that).

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlShowA">
    <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="dosomething()" />
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlShowB">
    <span>You don't have permission to see the button</span>
</asp:Panel>
```

Use one `asp:Panel` to warp your full content, and on code behind you open it and close it.

```
public partial class OnePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            pnlShowA.Visible = true;
            pnlShowB.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            pnlShowA.Visible = false;
            pnlShowB.Visible = true;
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the question is not about using ASP.NET Web Forms versus ASP.Net MVC. I felt compelled to point out that it may be more beneficial going with ASP.NET MVC rather than ASP.NET Web Forms in your scenario.

I say this because Classic ASP and ASP.NET MVC inline style is similar. In most cases you could probably convert ASP (`<% %>`) to Razor(a different flavor of in-lining server-side code with HTML) with little modification to the underlining logic. I don't know about you but the less code I have to write the better. For example, your above code would convert to the following Razor syntax:

```
   @if (condition) {

         <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="dosomething()" />

   }
   else {

         <span>You don't have permission to see the button</span>

   }
```

To answer your question, I would disable the button on the server-side. Have a  disabled on the client. In the case the button is disabled, enable the Label with the appropriate text.

```
//Code-behind
   bool correctPermission = true;

   submit.Enabled = correctPermission;
   noPermissionMessage.Enabled = !correctPermission;

//Client Code


<asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Click Me" />
<asp:Label ID="noPermissionMessage" runat="server" Text="You don't have permission to see the button" Enabled="false" />
```